# How to apply a horizontal scrolling bar for a table

Tags: javascript, html, css

Can anyone help me how to do this.
I have attached my code below. I tried doing it . But it is not working properly.

http://jsfiddle.net/Akz8j/15/

While entering number in column 7, accordingly the number of columns will get added.

But the scroll bar is not working.

without that i need to have the other table just below to the total members column, with same width and height

can anyone help me in this.

Thanks all..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are couple problems:

1. Your html isn't valid. You don't have closing `div` tags.
2. I've removed `align=right` on the table because it couses problem with scroll.

Code: http://jsfiddle.net/Akz8j/16/

Answer (score 0):

Remove both align and width attributes from member_table, ie. change your html from:

```
<table align="right" width="70%" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="2" border="1" id="member_table">
```

To

```
<table cellpadding="1" cellspacing="2" border="1" id="member_table">
```

Then your scroll bar will works.